# AS3 - Assigning array2's variables to array1's

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm trying to assign `array2` to `array1` by using: `array2 = array1`, but the problem is, and as it's mentioned here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html

> Array assignment is by reference rather than by value. When you assign one array variable to another array variable, both refer to the same array

I thought of using a for-loop, and it worked perfectly, but I feel like there must be faster and more simple.

Here's my loop, if anyone's interested:

```
for (var n:int = 0; n < array1.length; n++)
{
    array2[n] = array1[n];
}
```

So, I was wondering, Is there a way to assign array2 to array1 **without using a loop**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `slice` method:

> Returns a new array that consists of a range of elements from the
>   original array, without modifying the original array. The returned
>   array includes the startIndex element and all elements up to, but not
>   including, the endIndex element.

`//default values of the parameters will return a copy of the array
array2 = array1.slice();`